# How to deal with &nbsp when using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri I have scraped a page and I am trying to find the total results unsuccessfully.

HTML Fragment (doc)

```
<div class="total_count">
    <b>Returned:</b>&nbsp;97&nbsp;results
</div>
```

Get that total count => 97

```
doc.search(".total_count").text.gsub(/[^0-9]/,'') #=> 497 !Oops
```

How can I get past `&nbsp;` ?

The text it returns is this

```
 doc.search(".total_count").text

"\r\n    Returned:\u00A0497\u00A0results\r\n"
```

So using  `doc.at(".total_count").text.match('\d+')` gives "496"

The node is

```
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1762914 name="div" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1762878 name=
class" value="total_count">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1767618 "\r\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML
:Element:0x1767e1c name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1767a98 "Returned:">]>, #<Nokogiri::X
L::Text:0x1767834 "\u00A0497\u00A0results\r\n">]>]
```

Nokogiri, Ruby Versions

```
C:\Ruby200>nokogiri -v
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
# Nokogiri (1.6.0)
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.6.0
    ruby:
      version: 2.0.0
      platform: i386-mingw32
      description: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      binding: extension
      source: system
      compiled: 2.8.0
      loaded: 2.8.0
```

Comment: Have you tried `.text.match('\d+')`?

Comment: http://www.vitarara.org/cms/hpricot_to_nokogiri_day_1 says @tenderlove recommends `gsub(/\302\240/, ' ')` - read for details

Comment: Why do you get `496` when the HTML shows `97`, and Nokogiri code show `497`. Please be consistent when doing your testing and reporting your results.

Comment: @SeamusAbshere, Be careful quoting articles from 2009. Nokogiri, and Ruby have changed just a little bit since then. The output quoted in the `gsub` is from the time when Ruby/Nokogiri/libxml didn't know about multi-byte characters.

Comment: @theTinMan agreed in general, but I don't believe Nokogiri's handling of `&nbsp;` has changed - then and now, it's converted to a unicode character that can confuse people's patterns - still, again, i appreciate your comprehensive approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `search` unless you want a [NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) returned. A NodeSet acts like an array of [Nodes](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html), so you have to be prepared to iterate over them, or you can get some really weird results.

Instead, start with something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="total_count">
    <b>Returned:</b>&nbsp;97&nbsp;results
</div>
EOT

doc.at('div').text.scan(/\d+/) # => ["97"]
doc.at('div').text[/\d+/] # => "97"
```

`at` returns the first node matching the selector. In this case it's the `<div>`. I can use class selectors too:

```
doc.at('.total_count').text[/\d+/] # => "97"
```

Next, instead of trying to use `gsub` to remove what you don't want, use a regular expression to match what you DO want. I repeatedly see code that gets that concept wrong, so make that a mantra. When using a regular expression, if you're trying to find or capture something, use a match. If you're removing or changing stuff use `sub` or `gsub`. Very, very, occasionally you'll have to mix the two, but it should be a rare exception.

The current version of Nokogiri (1.6.0) using libxml (2.8.0), on a current version of Ruby (2.0.0) returns the `<div>` text node:

```
doc.at('div').text # => "\n    Returned:\u00A097\u00A0results\n"
```

There is no `4`, so if you are seeing anything different then you need to upgrade Ruby, Nokogiri and maybe even your libXML2.

You can check the version information using `nokogiri -v` at the command-line. You should see something like:

```
# Nokogiri (1.6.0)
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.6.0
    ruby:
      version: 2.0.0
      platform: x86_64-darwin12.4.0
      description: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      binding: extension
      source: packaged
      libxml2_path: /Users/tinman/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0
      libxslt_path: /Users/tinman/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxslt/1.1.26
      compiled: 2.8.0
      loaded: 2.8.0
```